# How to rename my JSON generated by pyspark?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

When i write my JSON file with

```
dataframe.coalesce(1).write.format('json')
```

on pyspark im not able to change the name of file in the partition

Im writing my JSON like that:

```
dataframe.coalesce(1).write.format('json').mode('overwrite').save('path')
```

but im not able to change the name of file in the partition

I want the path like that:

/folder/my_name.json

where 'my_name.json' is a json file

Comment: i do not think, you can control name of the output file. you can give only the folder name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spark **`we can't control name of the file`** written to the directory.

First write the data to the **`HDFS directory`** then For changing the name of file we need to use **`HDFS api`**.

**`Example:`**

**`In Pyspark:`**

```
l=[("a",1)]
ll=["id","sa"]
df=spark.createDataFrame(l,ll)

hdfs_dir = "/folder/" #your hdfs directory
new_filename="my_name.json" #new filename

df.coalesce(1).write.format("json").mode("overwrite").save(hdfs_dir)

fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())

#list files in the directory

list_status = fs.listStatus(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dir))

#filter name of the file starts with part-

file_name = [file.getPath().getName() for file in list_status if file.getPath().getName().startswith('part-')][0]

#rename the file

fs.rename(Path(hdfs_dir+''+file_name),Path(hdfs_dir+''+new_filename))
```

In case if you want to delete **`success files`** in the directory use `fs.delete` to delete `_Success` files.

**`In Scala:`**

```
val df=Seq(("a",1)).toDF("id","sa")
df.show(false)

import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

val hdfs_dir = "/folder/"
val new_filename="new_json.json"

df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("json").save(hdfs_dir)

val fs=FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
val f=fs.globStatus(new Path(s"${hdfs_dir}" + "*")).filter(x => x.getPath.getName.toString.startsWith("part-")).map(x => x.getPath.getName).mkString

fs.rename(new Path(s"${hdfs_dir}${f}"),new Path(s"${hdfs_dir}${new_filename}"))

fs.delete(new Path(s"${hdfs_dir}" + "_SUCCESS"))
```

Comment: not sure how you would use the java Path class in python correctly

Answer (score 1):

Extension to the answer accepted. For the people who are working with **AWS S3**

Following worked for me,

```
# Save the file to S3 bucket
spark_df.repartition(1).write.mode('append').parquet("s3://bucket_name/folder_name")

myPath = "s3://bucket_name/folder_name/*"

hadoopPath = SparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(myPath)

hadoopFs = hadoopPath.getFileSystem(SparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration())

statuses = hadoopFs.globStatus(hadoopPath)

file_name = [file.getPath().getName() for file in statuses if file.getPath().getName().startswith('part-')][0]

hadoopFs.rename(SparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(f"s3://bucket_name/folder_name/{file_name}"), SparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("s3://bucket_name/folder_name/myFile.parquet"))
```

Comment: For Azure (specifically Databricks) you need to replace the config line with the following:

`hadoopFs = hadoopPath.getFileSystem(spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())`