# Rename the folder created as a result of partitionBy

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I'm adding a column for the timestamp the job was run on the glue. I want to save it by using `partitionBy(load_timestamp)`. A folder was created as e.g. `load_timestamp=2020-04-27 03:21:54.`
I want the folder to be named as `table_name=2020-04-27 03:21:54.` Is this possible?

```
enriched = df.withColumn("load_timestamp", unix_timestamp(lit(timestamp),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp"))
enriched.write.partitionBy("load_timestamp").format("parquet").mode("append").save("s3://s3-enriched-bucket/" + job_statement[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Spark creates `directories` based on the partition column i.e.

**`<partition_column_name>=<value>`**

**`Easiest way`** to fix is to keep column name as `table_name` and use in **partition by** clause.

```
enriched = df.withColumn("table_name", unix_timestamp(lit(timestamp),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp"))

enriched.write.partitionBy("table_name").format("parquet").mode("append").save("s3://s3-enriched-bucket/" + job_statement[0])
```

**`Other way would be:`**

Renaming the directories by iterating using [**`hadoop.fs file API`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58172249) and change `load_timestamp` to `table_name`.