# Pyspark renaming file in HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, apache-spark-2.3

I'm using spark 2.3.1 and want to rename HDFS file in pyspark program.
I'm following this answer[https://stackoverflow.com/a/58172249/12927963] (Pyspark)

For this line

**fs.rename(Path(hdfs_dir+''+file_name),Path(hdfs_dir+''+new_filename))**

I'm getting following Error.

> NameError: name 'Path' is not defined

If I remove Path keyword from line

I'm getting following error.

> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o562.rename. Trace:
>   py4j.Py4JException: Method rename([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]) does not exist

So How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define path as

```
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
```