# Rename files after writing dataframe as CSV in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to write a parquet file into CSV using the `df.write.csv` but the output CSV file has a big name (part -0000- ), how can I rename that?

I searched and I found that it can be done in scala using the following code.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
fs = FileSystem.get(spark.hadoopConfiguration)

fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.rename(new Path("csvDirectory/data.csv/part-0000"), new Path("csvDirectory/newData.csv"))
```

How can it be done in pyspark?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171365/how-to-rename-my-json-generated-by-pyspark)

Comment: is it possible with python? thanks in advancce

Comment: if your dataframe isnt huge, use `pandas.to_csv()` after converting the df `toPandas`, there is a reason why spark writes the data in parts

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done with Spark directly. The solution in Scala can be adapted to Python :

```py
fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())


def rename(old_file_name, new_file_name):
    fs.rename(
        spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(old_file_name),
        spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(new_file_name),
    )
```

Comment: the above solution doesn't work with pyspark .  please let me know if there is any other way to catch it before printing it out

Comment: @NEERAJGHATE see my edit

Comment: What is the point of this?

Comment: @Steven thank you 11

Comment: @thebluephantom i am trying ro extract parquet file efficiently. still learning!