# How to rename a parquet file in pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a pyspark code as below which has 15 rows in it.

```
investor_df.write.parquet("s3a://dat-zone/piok/"+str(today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),mode="overwrite")
```

I need to rename it as investment.parquet. How to achieve this in pyspark?

Current filename

```
part-00000-3d8ec315-1cc8-414d-baa4-e555949d2fd5-c000.snappy.parquet
```

Expected name:

```
investment.parquet
```

Thanks,
Xi

Comment: Are you using Databricks?

Comment: no local Spark--> AWS EMR

Comment: Then, you can't rename it directly from Spark. You will have to use a Hadoop api. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171365/how-to-rename-my-json-generated-by-pyspark

Comment: ok will check , thanks