# Pyspark renaming and moving files in S3

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have to rename and move the output of my AWS Glue job to another folder in S3. I followed one of the reply from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70847534/15505231).

For the line below, I tried to put in a subfolder after `folder_name` hoping it will be created.

```
hadoopFs.rename(SparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(f"s3://bucket_name/folder_name/{file_name}"), SparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("s3://bucket_name/folder_name/myFile.parquet"))
```

It did not create the subfolder and the file will only be renamed and moved if it's already existing. I'm trying to create the subfolder with name as date format `YYYYMMDD`.

I have this code but it's not working.

```
currentdate = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
hadoopFs.rename(SparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(f"s3://bucket_name/folder_name/{file_name}"), SparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("s3://bucket_name/folder_name/"+currentdate+"/myFile.parquet"))
```

Is there any way to achieve this?